# What are the protocols used by azure data factory while using file system linked service?

Tags: azure, https, azure-data-factory

I am using file system linked service to connect with an on-prem network file location (self hsoted IR is used). If someone asks what protocols are using used from a security standpoint, what would be the answers?
Assume the domain is behind corporate firewall.

Answer (score 0):

The following are the Security protocols that are used by Azure Data Factory
for any type of linked service.
•   TLS (Transport Layer Security)
•   SSL (Secure Sockets Layer)
•   HTTPS (Hypertext Transfer Protocol Secure)
You can connect an on-premises network (Self Hosted IR) to your virtual network by setting up protocols like IPSec VPN (site-to-site) or ExpressRoute (private peering).
Please Refer these to learn more about Security in Azure Data Factory :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-movement-security-considerations
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-are-azure-data-security-features/

Comment: If the corporate firewall is not having https, would the IR use or fall back to the http?

Comment: As per the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime, if you want to perform data integration securely in a private network environment, which doesn't have a direct line-of-sight from the public cloud environment, you can install a self-hosted IR on premises environment behind your corporate firewall, or inside a virtual private network. The self-hosted integration runtime only makes outbound HTTP-based connections to open internet.